# Photoshop: export layers to files adding group-name as prefix

Tags: photoshop-script

I need to save hundreds layers as jpg files from a given psd.
Leyers are grouped in several groups and every group's name should compare as the prefix in the jpg's files.

Group1
  |
  layer1
  |
  layer2
  |
  layer3

Group2 
  |
  layer1
  |
  layer2

I need something like this:

Group1-layer1.jpg
Group1-layer2.jpg
Group1-layer3.jpg
Group2-layer1.jpg
Group2-layer2.jpg

I found many .jsx scripts that merge and export groups but can't find anything according to my needs. Does anyone know how to do that?
thank you
ema

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
#target photoshop
//$.level = 2;

/*
 *  Script by Loginoff Nick (nloginoff (at) gmail dot com)
 *  Script export layers to files adding group-name as prefix or create folders like a groups
 *  Function translite - replac a russian words to english.
 *  Photoshop CS5
 *  04.02.2014
 *  
 */


var LONG_NAMES = 0; // Save Long Names - Folder_SubFolder_Layer or save only "Layer"
var CREATE_FOLDERS = 1; // Create Hierarchy Folders. Warning if this 0 and LONG_NAMES = 0, maybe recreate files.
var SEPARATOR = '_'; // Separator for file name
var PREFIX_FILE = '' + SEPARATOR; // 


function main(){
    if(!documents.length) return;
    var doc = activeDocument;
    var DocPath = activeDocument.path;
    var DocName = translite(doc.name.replace(/\.psd/g,''));

    var outFolder = new Folder(DocPath + "/" + DocName + "_layers");
    if (!outFolder.exists) {
        outFolder.create();
    }

    scanLayers(doc,outFolder,PREFIX_FILE + DocName);

    function scanLayers(el, current_folder, prefix_name) {

        for(var a=0;a<el.layers.length;a++) {
            var lname = translite(el.layers[a].name);
            var file_name = lname;
            if ( LONG_NAMES ) {
                file_name = prefix_name + SEPARATOR + lname;
            }

            saveLayer(el.layers[a], file_name, current_folder, false);

            // recurstion
            if ( el.layers[a].layers && el.layers[a].layers.length > 0 ) {
                var new_folder = current_folder;
                if ( CREATE_FOLDERS ) {
                    new_folder = current_folder + "/" + lname;
                    var destFolder = new Folder(new_folder);
                    if (!destFolder.exists) {               
                        destFolder.create();
                    }
                }
                scanLayers(el.layers[a], new_folder, file_name);
            }
        }
    }

    function translite(str){
        var arr={'а':'a', 'б':'b', 'в':'v', 'г':'g', 'д':'d', 'е':'e', 'ж':'g', 'з':'z', 'и':'i', 'й':'y', 'к':'k', 'л':'l', 'м':'m', 'н':'n', 'о':'o', 'п':'p', 'р':'r', 'с':'s', 'т':'t', 'у':'u', 'ф':'f', 'ы':'i', 'э':'e', 'А':'A', 'Б':'B', 'В':'V', 'Г':'G', 'Д':'D', 'Е':'E', 'Ж':'G', 'З':'Z', 'И':'I', 'Й':'Y', 'К':'K', 'Л':'L', 'М':'M', 'Н':'N', 'О':'O', 'П':'P', 'Р':'R', 'С':'S', 'Т':'T', 'У':'U', 'Ф':'F', 'Ы':'I', 'Э':'E', 'ё':'yo', 'х':'h', 'ц':'ts', 'ч':'ch', 'ш':'sh', 'щ':'shch', 'ъ':'', 'ь':'', 'ю':'yu', 'я':'ya', 'Ё':'YO', 'Х':'H', 'Ц':'TS', 'Ч':'CH', 'Ш':'SH', 'Щ':'SHCH', 'Ъ':'', 'Ь':'','Ю':'YU', 'Я':'YA'};
        var replacer=function(a){return a in arr ? arr[a] : '';};
        return str.replace(/[А-яёЁьЬ]/g,replacer).toLowerCase();
    }

};

main();

function saveLayer(layer, lname, path, shouldMerge) {
    activeDocument.activeLayer = layer;
    dupLayers();
    if (shouldMerge === undefined || shouldMerge === true) {
        activeDocument.mergeVisibleLayers();
    }
    activeDocument.trim(TrimType.TRANSPARENT,true,true,true,true);
    var saveFile= File(path +"/"+lname+'.png');
    SavePNG(saveFile);
    app.activeDocument.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);
};

function dupLayers() { 
    var desc143 = new ActionDescriptor();
        var ref73 = new ActionReference();
        ref73.putClass( charIDToTypeID('Dcmn') );
    desc143.putReference( charIDToTypeID('null'), ref73 );
    desc143.putString( charIDToTypeID('Nm  '), activeDocument.activeLayer.name );
        var ref74 = new ActionReference();
        ref74.putEnumerated( charIDToTypeID('Lyr '), charIDToTypeID('Ordn'), charIDToTypeID('Trgt') );
    desc143.putReference( charIDToTypeID('Usng'), ref74 );
    executeAction( charIDToTypeID('Mk  '), desc143, DialogModes.NO );
};

function SavePNG(saveFile){
    var pngOpts = new ExportOptionsSaveForWeb; 
    pngOpts.format = SaveDocumentType.PNG
    pngOpts.PNG8 = false; 
    pngOpts.transparency = true; 
    pngOpts.interlaced = false; 
    pngOpts.quality = 100;
    activeDocument.exportDocument(new File(saveFile),ExportType.SAVEFORWEB,pngOpts); 
};
```